# How to deploy Fiori Launchpad on HANA XS running with HANA DB?

Tags: hana, sap-fiori, hana-xs, s4hana

If the system landscape has HANA XS running in HANA DB, is it possible to deploy FIORI launchpad in the landscape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the necessary steps are described in the official [SAP HANA XS Advanced Developer Guide](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4505d0bdaf4948449b7f7379d24d0f0d/2.0.03/en-US/fdb899c213d449158836669840fd2690.html)

Basically you have to do following steps:

- Enabled the SAP Fiori Launchpad Site Feature in the SAP Web IDE for SAP HANA
- Create a SAP Fiori Launchpad Site Module in your MTA Application
- Build and deploy the module
- Assign your UI5/Web Application to the Launchpad Site via configuration (as described in the online help)

Comment: Hello Florian. Thank you for your quick response. I shall go through the guide and the follow the steps. I also wanted to understand that where and how the FIORI Front End Server is deployed to run the FIORI Launchpad on HAHA XS. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: On HANA XSA there is no Fiori Frontend Server deployed, the HANA XSA server is the run environment for the Launchpad.

Comment: Thank You Florian for your response.

Comment: Hello Florian. So if we can create a Launchpad site using SAP Web IDE and deploy it on HANA XS, then we do not need an ABAP front end server to run FIORI applications on HANA XS ? Also, in this landscape what would be the FIORI version, and how can we use Notification centre feature of FIORI Launchpad ? Thank you.

Comment: @ShivamBedwal, did you manage to launch your Fiori Launchpad? What to do if we have more than one app? How to load them into one launchpad?